# Does F# support multiple dispatch / multi methods?

Tags: f#

I checked the F# example and it looks like that

```
// define the square function
let square x = x * x

// define the sumOfSquares function
let sumOfSquares n = 
   [1..n] |> List.map square |> List.sum

// try it
sumOfSquares 100
```

From that usage it seems like F# does not support multiple dispatch, otherwise it would be written as

```
...
let sumOfSquares n = 
   [1..n] |> map square |> sum
...
```

So, does it support multiple dispatch or not or has some limited support?

Comment: It does, just like any other .NET language. All collections in .NET inherit from `IEnumerable<T>` which means the example could easily be `[1..n] |> Seq.map square |> Seq.sum`. A `Seq` in F# is essentially an `IEnumerable<T>` but you shouldn't say that, gives the impression that it's just .NET under the syntax.

Comment: Another thing you shouldn't say is `why not use LINQ then, why not make *that* the simplified syntax?`. That would imply that F# could gain something from C#, which is obviously impossible. Although you *can* use a [query expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/query-expressions) to write LINQ queries that include the operators you typically can't use in C# queries, like `count` and `sumBy`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

F# does not support multiple dispatch in the way you would like to use it.  For methods on classes, it does support overload resolution, which is similar.  In your example, `List.map` and `List.sum` are functions on the `List` module and therefore are not eligible for overload resolution since F# functions cannot be overloaded.

Answer (score 4):

F# does support overload resolution on methods, for functions it's a bit more complicated as there is no direct support but you could achieve it by creating inline functions that call overloaded methods, which will result in a trait call.

You can find out how it works [here](http://nut-cracker.azurewebsites.net/blog/2011/10/05/inlinefun).

And a good example of this is found in the [FSharpPlus library](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharpPlus), with it you can write your code as it is:

In your example:

```
open FSharpPlus

// define the square function
let square x = x * x

// define the sumOfSquares function
let sumOfSquares n = 
   [1..n] |> map square |> sum

// try it
sumOfSquares 100

// also with arrays !
let sumOfSquares2 n = 
   [|1..n|] |> map square |> sum

sumOfSquares2 100
```

Now, what if you want to sum floats? It won't work unless you make your `square` function inline:

```
// define the square function
let inline square x = x * x

// with floats
let sumOfSquares3 n = 
   [1.0 .. n] |> map square |> sum

// try it
sumOfSquares3 100.0

// val it : float = 338350.0
```